# Undefined Reference when Compiling to Executable

Tags: c++

When I try to compile all of my object files into an executable, I get the error

`lab5.o:lab5.cpp: undefined reference to 'Card::suitMap'`

I assume it's an issue with correctly linking dependencies, but I don't really know how to verify whether I'm on the right track.

Here's the source file containing the `main` function:

```
#include "Card.h"
#include "Deck.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Deck* deck1 = new Deck();
    Deck* deck2 = new Deck();

    for(int i = 0; i < deck1->deck.size(); i++)
    {
        Card card = deck1->draw();
        cout << card.getSuit() << " " << card.getValue() << endl;
    }

    deck2->shuffle();
    for(int i = 0; i < deck2->deck.size(); i++)
    {
        Card card = deck2->draw();
        cout << card.getSuit() << " " << card.getValue() << endl;
    }
}
```

Here's my Card.h which contains suitMap

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Card {
private:
    int value;
    int suit;
public:
    std::map <int, std::string> suitMap;
    Card(int value, int suit);
    int getValue() { return this->value; }
    std::string getSuit() { return this->suitMap.find(this->suit)->second; }
};

#endif
```

I'm not sure if my makefile could contain the problem, but here it is as well

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -g -std=c++11
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=lab5.cpp Card.cpp Deck.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=lab5

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: did you `#include "Card.h"` in lab5.cpp ?

Comment: @tobi303 Yep, it's the first line. That's why I'm confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have had `suitMap` previously denoted `static`, and somehow not obtained a clean build after changing that. Be sure to perform a full clean build after modifying headers.

Comment: That was the issue. I could have sworn I ran `make clean` before posting, but I guess I didn't. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @John: This is a flaw in the makefile.  A correctly designed makefile eliminates the need for clean builds.

Comment: @nobar: Header change detection is overkill for a tiny project of three source files. It could be introduced later.

Comment: The "overkill"  would have saved to OP some confusion in this case.  With a nice makefile template, it shouldn't require a significant per-project effort.  Arguably, this project doesn't require a makefile at all, but if you're going to have a makefile, it might as well work properly.  If nothing else, it could *always* do a from-scratch build to ensure that everything is up-to-date.  For such a small project, that probably wouldn't be too expensive.

Comment: @nobar: On the other hand just writing `make clean all` is very easy and then you can just move on

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to a flaw in the makefile.  A correctly designed makefile automatically manages all dependencies and thereby eliminates the need for running `make clean` to *fix* a build.

Below is an example makefile that would have prevented your problem.  Rather than doing incremental builds, it always recompiles every source file.  As you create larger projects, this approach may eventually become too slow, in which case you will want to invest in a more sophisticated build management solution.  For your existing project, with this makefile, builds will likely take around one second on a modern PC.

```
EXECUTABLE = lab5
SOURCES += lab5.cpp Card.cpp Deck.cpp

CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Werror
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS += -g

.PHONY: build
build:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(SOURCES) $(LDLIBS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: I included a `make clean` target because that can be useful when working with an SCM (such as [Git](https://git-scm.com/)) -- not because you need it to fix an out-of-sync build.